# Why we can't subscript 'int' object in Python

Tags: python, int

I'm trying to return the days of the month according to the given year, in the end, if the year isn't leap, it should return the no of days according to the defined list, but I'm getting error.

Here's my code

```
days_of_month=[0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
year=int(input('enter the year - '))
month=int(input('enter the month - '))

def isleap(year):
    return year%4==0 and (year % 100!=0 or year % 400==0)
def days(month,year):
    if month > 12 or month < 1:
        print('Invalid')     
    else:
        if month==2 and isleap(year):
            return 29
        else:
            return month[days_of_month]    

print(days(month,year))
```

Error Message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Function_Example.py", line 16, in <module>
    print(days(month,year))
  File "d:\Function_Example.py", line 14, in days
    return month[days_of_month]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Is there any onther way to get the element from the list ?

Comment: `month` is an integer, not a list. I think you want `days_of_month[month]`, not the other way round.

Comment: "Why we can't subscript 'int' object in Python"—why should we be able to? What would subscripting an integer mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you confused the last line of the function.

it should be:

```
days_of_month=[0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
year=int(input('enter the year - '))
month=int(input('enter the month - '))

def isleap(year):
    return year%4==0 and (year % 100!=0 or year % 400==0)
def days(month,year):
    if month > 12 or month < 1:
        print('Invalid')     
    else:
        if month==2 and isleap(year):
            return 29
        else:
            return days_of_month[month]    

print(days(month,year))
```